# PHP CForm::element collection does not work in yii framework?

Tags: php, yii

I want to create simple form using CForm (yii framework) but 'elements' => array('username'=>array('type'=>'text')) does not generate input element.

Comment: Does the model object have 'username' attribute?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [CForm doc](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CForm):

> The above code specifies two input elements: 'username' and
>   'password'. Note the model object must have exactly the same
>   attributes 'username' and 'password'.

So I guess 'username' attibute should be added to the model object as well.